# How to return base64Encoded Matplotlib Chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In my matplotlib python code, I have a **plt.savefig('test_file.png')** and that, of course, works as expected.

But, since this code will be used in a REST service, I need to return the file contents as a Base64Encoded string to the caller (so they can Decode it and view it as png graphics file).

I tried this approach below, but it doesn't generate a large enough file (the actual png created by the plt.saveFig() is about 100KB, this approach below is only 4 KB):

```
my_stringIObytes = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(my_stringIObytes, format='png')
my_stringIObytes.seek(0)
my_base64_jpgData = base64.b64encode(my_stringIObytes.read())
```

And using the above "my_stringIObytes", I also tried saving this directly to disk (with no encoding), like this:

```
with open('base64_decode_test.png', 'wb') as fl:
    fl.write(my_stringIObytes.getbuffer())
    fl.close()
```

But that did not work either...

It looks like my initial attempt in the first code snippet above is probably the culprit, but I can't find any good examples of how do to what I need.

Would appreciate suggestions.

Thanks very much,

M

Comment: maybe a bit unrelated, but [this link](https://matplotlib.org/3.4.2/gallery/user_interfaces/web_application_server_sgskip.html) recommends when using Matplotlib in a web server it  to not use pyplot